# Thunderbird (31.6) does not filter by reply-to email address

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention, email-filter

I have recently received SPAM where I'd like the given reply-to address to be the filter criterion.

However, Thunderbird 31.6 doesn't offer a "Reply-To" in the dropdown for filtering:

[image: Screenshot of filter criteria not offering reply-to address]

Note that German "Von" = "From" and "An" = "To", but there's no "Antwort an" = "Reply To" in the dropdown.

As of now, I cannot filter that thing the way I want to.

**Q's**:
What's wrong?

Is it a bug/missing feature?

Are there any manual hacks to get it done?

---

**UPDATE 1**

I tried as kaarel suggested, but it didn't work. "Reply-To" isn't accepted, not is "Antwort-an" and "Antwort an" gives me the following error:

[image]

How does TB know from a custom string, e.g. "Reply-To" that it is supposed to check the reply-to email address?

Comment: _Reply-To_ (written exactly like that) is a standard e-mail header, that's how Thunderbird knows what to check. What do you mean by “it isn’t accepted” — does it let you add the filtering rule with _Reply-To_ but it doesn’t work as expected or do you get some error message when adding _Reply-To_ as well?

Comment: I added the "Reply-To" according to the picture, but executing the filter manually on the CORRECT folder doesn't work - the email is still there.

Comment: I tested it with my Thunderbird installation (I didn’t note the version number though) and it worked. Then, after Thunderbird asked to update itself to a newer version and I let it, the filter stopped working. I found this [bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622307) where it’s reported that filtering by custom headers seems to be buggy in some versions of Thunderbird – so I guess you have everything set up correctly and it’s just a bug in Thunderbird.

Comment: Strange. The bug report says to have no problems when running the filter on the whole folder manually. I'll comment it there and hope it will be fixed soon/someday. (BTW: since you found out it's a bug, your comment actually qualifies as an answer... maybe you want to update it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don’t know whether to call it a missing feature or just a missing option. Luckily you can add e-mail headers to filter on – from the filtering dropdown choose *Anpassen…* (*Customize…* for Thunderbird with English UI) at the bottom, and add *Reply-To* as a new value.

Update: as reported in [this Bugzilla thread](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=622307), several versions of Thunderbird have a bug, that prevents filtering on custom e-mail headers, so this solution might not work for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Reply-to would work, however spammers do not include the hyphen, so to make up "reply to" without the hyphen is not accepted when adding this to the filter due to the space. Spaces are not accepted as an ASCII character.
I get hundreds of email from one spammer 5h64wg3x395@schoolsuk.com and this email is not accepted, something has to be done about it.